# Error while adding repository in Ubuntu 16.10 (keyserver recieve failed)

Tags: apt, repository, 16.10, keyserver

Whenever I try adding a repository in my Ubuntu 16.10 I am getting keyserver recieve failed error. 
For example on adding pycharm repo I am getting this error:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mystic-mirage/pycharm
 The Most Intelligent Python IDE

Enjoy productive Python, Django, and Web development with PyCharm, an intelligent Python IDE offering unique coding experience

This PPA contains both PyCharm Professional and Community Editions

Update 2016-07-22: Unity Menubar Integration enabled. Enjoy!
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~mystic-mirage/+archive/ubuntu/pycharm
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmppoqic2l4/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you ever able to solve this? Thanks.